# Xcode 4.2 won't recognize C++ raw string literals?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

I'm trying to pick up the basics of C++11. I have Xcode 4.2 on my mac, which uses the LLVM 3.0 compiler. From what I read, it should have support for raw string literals (i.e. `R"(...)"`) but when I try to compile something with them, it barfs at me. I have set it up for c++0x (I turned on `-std=c++0x` and the libc++ library) and I know it works with other c++0x features like the range for-loop.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly Apple clang 3.0 (that comes with Xcode 4.2) != clang 3.0 ([which supports raw string literals](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html).)

You'll need to wait for a later version of Xcode, or [build more recent versions of clang/llvm/libc++ from source](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html).

Comment: If you have Macports, you can also grab maintained code for 2.9 (the current default) or 3.0 (you need to specify `clang3.0`).

Comment: I think I may use stick with my non-Apple approved build of gcc 4.6.2. I really wanted to use Xcode, but oh well hahaha.